# What's the use of deleteCharAt() in Java StringBuffer?

Tags: java, stringbuffer

We already have `delete()` in `StringBuffer`. Why do we need `deleteCharAt()`?
Wouldn't `deleteCharAt(n)` and `delete(n, n+1)` do the same?

Comment: which *deleteCharAt()* are you talking about? I don't see that method.  That said, it will probably come to you as a surprise but *deleteCharAt(...)* does **NOT** delete the character at ... anymore since Java 1.4.  That method, just as the whole *char* abstraction shortsightedly stored on 16-bits, only made sense up to Unicode 3.0.  Since Unicode 3.1 there are codepoints located above 65 535 and, for Java, it means we're in a SNAFU you'd have a hard time realizing (basically for a lot of applications *char* is pointless, the Character wrapper is pointless and.. (to be continued)

Comment: .. and many old methods like *deleteCharAt(n)* hardly make any sense anymore).  You may want to check String and StringBuffer's *codePointAt(n)* JavaDoc to if you're interested in this issue.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r - I'm pretty sure he's talking about [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#deleteCharAt(int)) *deleteCharAt()*.

Comment: There is one more if check at most, and one bit of math... hardly a performance bottleneck. This kind of method is a convenience method. It is useful b/c it produces self documenting code. Nobody needs to determine what start and end are at a given point, and then figure out what the code is doing. It is more obvious (it's deleting a single character) and therefore more maintainable

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the source tells that delete() is not using deleteCharAt() and viceversa for their implementation. I notice a small diference: deleteCharAt will throw an Exception if index is not in bounds, while delete will default to the length of the string when the second argument passes the string length.

But the effect on the string buffer contents is the same.

Comment: *Both* methods will throw an exception if the start index is out of bounds in either direction, so no difference there, at least not since Java 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is simplicity.  Why should two parameters be necessary to remove a single character?

Another possibility is that `delete()` is implemented in terms of `deleteCharAt()`, and since `deleteCharAt()` therefore needs to exist anyways and is useful by itself it was simply declared public.  But one can [look at the source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.html) and see that this is not the case here.  But it is a common pattern in many other Java classes.

A third possibility is that because the method is able to assume that it is deleting a single character, `deleteCharAt()` can be implemented in a way that is more efficient than the more generic `delete()`.  Again however the source code rules this option out.  Both methods resolve to nearly identical calls to `System.arraycopy()`.

So given that, I have the vote for the first option.  It was done solely to simplify the relatively common use-case of deleting a single character by reducing the number of parameters the programmer needs to supply from 2 to 1.

Comment: Simplicity and clarity, most likely.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the source code. So the benefits of using _deleteCharAt()_ are simplicity and efficiency. I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Difference is the implementation of the functions DeleteAt is a single statement like removing from list list.remove(index) delete takes two parameter and makes a loop starts from starting index and call remove function untill the second parameter.

Comment: both `delete` and `deleteCharAt` use the native method `System.arraycopy`, no loop involved (despite inside `arraycopy`)

Answer (score 0):

There are efficiencies that can be exploited within the implementation of `deleteCharAt`, because the method knows it is deleting *exactly one* character.

Conversely, deleting a *series* of characters in `delete(n, m)` may require more complex execution paths that are necessarily more expensive because they "do more".

Although `delete(n, n+1)` has the same effect as `deleteCharAt(n)`, deleteCharAt will probably be faster. (The optimizer may convert one to the other!). It certainly won't be slower.

Comment: I thought so too, but the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.html) seems to rule this out.  Both methods use identical `System.arraycopy()` calls to overwrite the char(s) being deleted.  As such, I'd expect the performance of either to be the same.

Comment: `delete` only does some more index checking - minimal improvement, if any.

Comment: @aroth that's true in *this* implementation. Also, I only said "efficiencies that *can be* exploited" - I didn't say they *were* exploited.

Answer (score 0):

You may obtain the same results but actually, there are a few efficiency issues here...

For deleting at a given index, one simple check on this index is enough while a few more are necessary when deleting a range of indexes.

See for yourself :

```
public AbstractStringBuilder delete(int start, int end) 
{
    if (start <  0)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(start);
    if (end  > count)
        end = count;
    if (start  > end)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    int len = end - start;
    if (len  > 0) {
        System.arraycopy(value, start+len, value, start, count-end);
        count -= len;
    }
    return this;
}
```

Compared to:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder deleteCharAt(int index) 
{
    if ((index <  0) || (index  >= count))
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    System.arraycopy(value, index+1, value, index, count-index-1);
    count--;
    return this;
}
```

Therefore, if you need to delete only one char, you better use deleteCharAt and save a few checks. Yet if you want to delete more than 1 consecutive char, prefer using delete so that only one call to arraycopy is made and the checkings are not repeated each time you call deleteCharAt :)

Comment: "Save a few checks". Thanks for making it clearer. Of course I will use _delete()_ to delete consecutive characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is one difference *** :
if `n`is the length of the text, that is `buffer.length()` then `deleteCharAt(n)` will throw an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, while `delete(n, n+1)` will do nothing at all - no Exception, nothing deleted.
For greater values of `n`, both will throw the Exception.

IMO it is better to use `deleteCharAt` because it is exactly what you want to do. Using `delete` is a little bit harder to understand.

*(and `delete` does more checking for the additional index)*

*** Java 1.6